# How to align some specific elements to horizontal while using the Column widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, properties, widget, alignment

How to align some specific elements to horizontal while using the Column widget?
void main(){
runApp(MaterialApp(
home:Home(),
));
}
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

```
   @override
  HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
  }

    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<Quote> quote=[
    Quote(text: 'Be yourself,everyone else is taken', author: 'King'),
   Quote(text: 'Work Hard , Dream Big', author: 'king'),
   Quote(text: 'Without Sacrifice there are no gains', author: 'king'),
  ];
  Widget Cardfunction(Quote){
 return Card(
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: [
      Text(
       Quote.text,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 20,
        ),
        ),
      ],
     ),
   );
  }
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Awesome Day',
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
    ),
    centerTitle: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent
    ),
     backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent[100],
     body: Column(
    children: quote.map((a){
     return Cardfunction(a);
         }).toList(),
         ),
       );
     }
   }
```

I am a beginner in flutter so here i am getting a new problem that is  I want to see the author name right after the text like....'Work hard,dream big- **king**' and author name with different style.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to combine two strings then you can use the + operator
Like,

```
 Text(
       Quote.text + '- ' + Quote.author,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 20,
        ),
        ),
```

That should give you "Work hard, dream big"- King.

Or if you want to align two widget together horizontally, then you can use the Row widget. Its the most common solution. Using rows within columns and using columns within rows is pretty common so you can try that.